# Django User Custom Permissions without using Django Admin & Groups?

Tags: python, django, authentication, permissions

I'm using a custom user model and trying to add permission to users that will be able to manage (only) their business profile.

I have two models that I need to connect.

Business & User

I will have four levels of user permissions.

```
1. No permission
2. Employee
3. Manager
4. Owner (can own multiple businesses)
```

I will need to have control, not to only control the permissions in my `views.py` but also in templates where each user may see slightly different content, links etc

So the million dollar question is:

**Option 1.**

Do I just simply add the `is_employee`, `is_manager` and `is_owner` fields directly to the user model as M2M fields and just check when the user is logged in for the permission?

**Option 2.**
Technically, I can also add those three permission fields `is_employee`, `is_manager` and `is_owner` to the business model as M2M fields and check whether the user is authorized to access the business data.

**Option 3.**

Create some kind of middle service layer (manager) functionality that will connect my views and models to handle this?

Or perhaps there is some use of Django Permissions for something like this?

Comment: The cleanest way is to use django groups, but it seems that's out of question. Do all of your users have the exact same model except for the permission level?

Comment: Yes, all users are stored in the same model. As per groups, I'm not sure how would that work if I have thousands of Businesses and would need a Group for each business ... unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You can just define the user with a field business. Then depending on the group every user can have different access to their respective business. The groups are for users, each group has different permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! That may work. How about using the `is_owner` field in the user model in stead of creating groups? Also, what if the business had a `user` M2M field instead of user the user model having a business field? I thought it would make more sense as it would be almost like business employees. Any advantages for the `business` field in the user model over `user` field in the business model?

Comment: You can have the field in any model, the issue is following the reverse relationship may be confusing sometimes at the start. You can have the field is_owner and show only owners certain content or allow them into certain views and it would work. If you haven't read about groups, please check: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#groups